# grails mockDomain() different behavior when running on test and all test-suite

Tags: unit-testing, grails, mocking

I'm using two mockDomain in a Unit Test. When I launch only one UT (using grails test-app -unit MyTest), the test passes ok but if I launch the whole test suite (grails test-app -unit), the tests where I've got two mockDomain defined failed.

Is there a difference in the way tests are run when launched once at a time or when the whole suite is launched ?

my code sample :

```
void testSaveTranslation_ok() {

    mockDomain(Translation)
    mockDomain(HelpSubject, [new HelpSubject(name_fr: "subject")])

    assertEquals(1, HelpSubject.count())
    HelpSubject helpSubject = HelpSubject.findAll().get(0)
    assertNull(helpSubject.name)

    def translation = new Translation(defaultVal:"defaultVal", enVal: "enVal", frVal: "frVal", meta: "helpSubject#name#${helpSubject.id}")
    assertEquals(0, Translation.count())

    translationService.saveTranslation(translation)
    assertEquals(1, Translation.count())

    assertNotNull(helpSubject.name)
}
```

Regards,

David.

Answer (score 0):

I see a difference how you mock Translation and HelpSubject.

Try using this: mockDomain(Translation,[translation])

Comment: If I do that (please correct me if I'm wrong), my translation instance will be saved so the assertEquals(0, Translation.count()) will fail. The concern of this test is to validate that the method     translationService.saveTranslation(translation) effectively save the translation.

Comment: I think you are correct, but that's what you want anyways. In Grails you don't actually have to call save() method on Domain object. If your object is attached to the session, participates in a transaction and is dirty (or new) it will be persisted whether you call save() on it or not. Now in your case you don't care, you just want to test saveTranslation() whatever it does. Keep in mind mockDomain is limited in scope and won't have all of your static methods and such - u going to have to meta program those in if needs be.